# Can't pin phpStorm64.exe to desired position in windows 10 Taskbar

Tags: windows, windows-10, 64-bit, taskbar, phpstorm

I'm using phpStorm on Windows 10 and would like to pin the application to a specific spot in the taskbar. While that works with the PhpStorm.exe it doesn't with the PhpStorm64.exe.
The pinned icon always appears as last icon in the taskbar and when I open the application with that icon I have two identical phpStorm icons in the taskbar.

Any ideas, why windows doesn't match the taskbar link with the startet application?

thanks, thomic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 10-specific bug, please vote for [IDEA-143209](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-143209) to be notified on updates